# PHP How to replace ini_set function

Tags: php

My application is using ini_set() to store relative path for my libraries/classes folders.

The problem is that some ISP disable this (and other) PHP functions. Therefore I get the following error:
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in /var/www/....

Is there any way to replace this function by anything else ?

Comment: Try going with a webhost that doesn't suck dinosaur balls?

Comment: I cant. It is an application that I provide for a lot of users, and they may have any hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`chdir`](http://php.net/chdir) to change the active working folder.

For example, I like to start my scripts with:

```
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Now I know that all my includes will work, no matter which folder the current script is in.

Comment: Am I correct that i have then to call this: require_once '/MyClass/MySuperClass.php'; ?

Comment: No. Remove that first slash, otherwise you're specifying from the root of the drive, which will almost certainly be a "Permission Denied" error.

Comment: fore sure, but I was more talking on the way to use then the include/require... I will need to deeply test. Many thanks.